# How the output of this program comes out to be this?

Tags: c

I have a piece of code written in C where some pointer arithmetic is performed. I would like to know how the output comes to be this?

```
#include <stdio.h>  
int main()
{
    char arr[] = "gookmforgookm";
    char *ptr1 = arr;
    char *ptr2 = ptr1 + 3;
    printf ("ptr2 - ptr1 = %d\n", ptr2 - ptr1);
    printf ("(int*)ptr2 - (int*) ptr1 = %d",  (int*)ptr2 - (int*)ptr1);
    getchar();
    return 0;
}
```

Output is below:

```
ptr2 - ptr1 = 3  
(int*)ptr2 - (int*) ptr1 = 0
```

Comment: interesting. I'll try to find a solution. +1

Answer (score 6, accepted):

Strictly speaking, you're invoking undefined behaviour and any result that the program produces is OK according to the C standard.

However, you're probably on a machine where `sizeof(int) == 4` (as opposed to say, 2).  Since there are 4 bytes to an integer, two addresses which are 3 bytes apart are part of the same integer, so the difference between the addresses is `0 * sizeof(int)`.  You might find a different answer if you chose `ptr1 = arr + 1;`, or you might not.  But that's the beauty of undefined behaviour - it would be 'right' either way.

Answer (score 4):

After the subtraction you need to divide the result in the size of the pointed type.

```
(int*)ptr2 - (int*)ptr1 == (0x1000003 - 0x1000000) / sizeof(int)
(int*)ptr2 - (int*)ptr1 == (0x1000003 - 0x1000000) / 4 == 0
```

Comment: Thanks @MByD But suppose my statment is like this printf ("(char*)ptr2 - (char*) ptr1 = %d",  (char*)ptr2 - (char*)ptr1);
and ptr1 and ptr2 are of type int in start then will we divide or mutliply ?

Answer (score 1):

`ptr1` and `ptr2` are both `char *` type, that means one byte one pointer.

```
char *ptr2 = ptr1 + 3;
```

so

```
ptr2 - ptr1 = 3
```

Next, you cast both pointer to type `int *`, `int` type need 4 byte, so both pointer aim at the same `int`, both pointer have the same value through the memory align, you get the `0` result.

Answer (score 0):

When you subtract two pointers, as long as they point into the same array, the result is the number of elements separating them.

[Pointer Subtraction and Comparison](http://c-faq.com/~scs/cclass/notes/sx10c.html)

Comment: I am more interested in looking for the answer for second part!!

Answer (score 0):

The memory addresses of the elements of the same array are always sequential. i.e 
if the memory adress of myarray[0] is:

```
 0x4000000
```

then the memory address of myarray[2] will definitely be

```
 0x4000002
```

So when you store the address of `arr` into `ptr1` assume it to be **x**
, and then when you make the address of `ptr2`, three units *higher* than ptr1, it will be **x+3**. So when you subtract ptr1 from ptr2 the answer will be:

> (**x**+3) - **x** = 3

Hence the answer.

In the second *printf()* statement, if you want it to display the same result as above (3), you have to convert the pointer to `int` and not `int*`.

```
char *myvar; // given contents somewhere
int addr = (int)myvar; // addr now = the char pointer
```

So In your case:

```
printf ("(int)ptr2 - (int) ptr1 = %d",  (int)ptr2 - (int)ptr1);
```